# Global variable counter wont change

Tags: python-2.7, global

I have this code I'm working on and the issue I'm having is that when the program adds the first character to the list, it won't change counter to "counter = counter + 1"

```
import random
import string

global counter
counter = 0

def diceroll():
    roll = random.randint(1,6)
    return roll

def codegen(dice,counter):
    if dice in [1,3,5]:
        list1[counter] = str(random.randint(0,9))
        counter = counter + 1
        if counter in [6,12,18,24]:
            counter = counter + 1
        else:
            pass
    elif dice in [2,4,6]:
        list1[counter] = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
        counter = counter + 1
        if counter in [6,12,18,24]:
            counter = counter + 1
        else:
            pass

list1 = ["-","-","-","-"]

print "Welcome to the Microsoft Code Generator"
ent = raw_input("\nPlease press Enter to generate your 25 character code: ")

while ent != "":
    print "\nYou did not press Enter"
    ent = raw_input("\nPlease press Enter to generate your 25 character code: ")

while len(list1) != 29:
    dice = diceroll()
    codegen(dice,counter)
else:
    print list1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're passing `counter` as an argument, that's shadowing the global variable. If you want to use the global variable, don't make it an argument to the `codegen` function.

```
def codegen(dice):
    if dice in [1,3,5]:
        list1[counter] = str(random.randint(0,9))
        counter = counter + 1
        if counter in [6,12,18,24]:
            counter = counter + 1
        else:
            pass
    elif dice in [2,4,6]:
        list1[counter] = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
        counter = counter + 1
        if counter in [6,12,18,24]:
            counter = counter + 1
        else:
            pass
...

while len(list1) != 29:
    dice = diceroll()
    codegen(dice)
else:
    print list1
```

Answer (score 0):

To use global variables in functions you must declare it as global if you want assign it. For example:

```
count = 0

def foo():
  global count
  count += 1
  print count
```

Calling `foo()` 3 times then checking `count` would result in the following

```
foo()
> 1
foo()
> 2
foo()
> 3
count
> 3
```

So as you can see, declaring `count` as global let us increment it. Declare your variable as `global` within the function, and **do not** pass it in as an argument (its global so you don't need to do this anyways).

Comment: Oh, yes I understand, that makes sense, I forgot about that you could increment instead of the longer reassigning method which caused the confusion for me, thank you for the help, much appreciated:)

Comment: I'm glad that helped! It can be a tricky little subject. If you wouldn't mind accepting my answer (assuming you figured it out with my help) I would appreciate it!

Comment: Although, now I'm getting an Unbound Local Error. Here's my updated code: http://pastebin.com/En0Vh6hU

Comment: Yes, you're close - your mistake is in the placement of ```global```.

Comment: At the top of your ```codegen``` function (before the conditionals), type the line ```global counter```. Right now Python thinks that the variable ```counter``` you are trying to use is local to ```codegen``` because you are not declaring it to be global **inside** the function.

You don't need to ```global counter``` at the top.

Comment: Oh, I see. The way I was taught global (and I've barely used it) was to put it at the top of the code so that it has "global scope" as per say, since it's on top of all of the code it should be accessible from everywhere was what I was told. However now its now saying that the "List assignment index is out of range"?

Comment: "List assignment index is out of range" means you are trying to assign something to a list index that doesn't exist in your ```list1```. When your ```counter``` variable reaches ```4```, it officially goes out of range of ```list1```, which you have set to have 4 values in it (so it ends at index 3). To **add values to list1**, you need to call ```list1.append(YOUR_VALUE)``` instead of ```list1[counter] = YOUR_VALUE```. ```.append``` adds values to the end of the list, whereas ```list[index]``` accesses **existing** indexes in your list.